# TorButton Security settings: Define custom level

Tags: security, tor-button, settings

Is there a way to define a custom level in the security settings?
For example I'd like to use the "safer" preset but allow Javascript on HTTP. The reason is that I use a separate JS blocker which allows me to select which scripts to trust (and which not to). However I'd like to use the reduced set of Fonts and the other measures of the "Safer" preset.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible and shouldn't be done.

The reason the security slider was introduced was to allow granular but consistent choices, providing intervals between reduced attack surface and usability.

Setting a custom level would make you distinguishable from other Tor Browser users, which would defeat the anonymity provided by Tor Browser.

One of the considerations *against* the security slider is that each setting makes you look different from other Tor Browser users, breaking Tor Browser users up into a smaller anonymity set and making you more trackable. Tor Browser aims to put all users into one anonymity set.

If you only need some features sometimes and want to not have them at others, you should set the slider appropriately for each situation.

Comment: Well, you cannot set it on a per-website basis, can you? There are still many websites that do not allow HTTPS and many of those do not work without JS.... - That would mean while using one of theses sites, all other websites can use for example non-standard fonts to track me.....

From the perspective you mentioned, Using NoScript or similar AddOns would be a bad idea, as every user would allow different domains which results in a difference in the execution of JS just like my requested custom security level would do. Same for AdBlock/uBlock.

Comment: What is the consistency in the choice that I need special Fonts and HTTP-JS both or not all?! And doesnt diabling JS mean that a website cannot even determine the installed fonts?!

Comment: Using panopticlick.eff.org i noticed that "safer" does not reduce the set of system fonts liste via JS. What does this setting change?! Or does ist block to load some "malicious" fonts from the web?!

Comment: Yes, customising noscript or installing ublock or adblock is a bad idea and will reduce your anonymity.

Comment: If you want to use sites with different requirements, e.g. one where you want javascript disabled and one that requires javascript, view them at different times.

Comment: the "safer" setting says what it changes and also provides a link with more information, you might try reading that next time: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/security-slider.html

Comment: Pretty funny; TorBrowser warns about using full screen mode, but according to the eff fingerprinting test, the browser is much less unique in in full screen mode then in (unaltered) windowed dimensions.
--------
@cacahuati yes, I will do a schedule when to visit which site and cluster that by http/https and JS needs - very handy....
"the more information" you reference is most likely "some font rendering features are disabled" - oooh yes, that is detailed. How could I missunderstand that o.0

Comment: EFF fingerprinting test isn't about being able to be distinguished from your anonymity set :) it's absolutely irrelevant in the context of Tor Browser. The security slider is about...security. Not anonymity, fingerprintability or trackability.